# Passing annotation to scheduled task in spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, kubernetes-cronjob

I am running SCDF on Kubernetes and have scheduled some tasks. I have to pass annotations to my tasks. I have given the following annotations in env:

```
    - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_KUBERNETES_POD_ANNOTATIONS
      value:
    - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_KUBERNETES_JOB_ANNOTATIONS
      value:
```

These work when i manually trigger the task. I also want these annotations to be added to pods created by scheduled cron jobs. How can i do that?

I tried the following annotations:

```
    - name: SPRING_CLOUD_SCHEDULER_KUBERNETES_POD_ANNOTATIONS
      value:
    - name: SPRING_CLOUD_SCHEDULER_KUBERNETES_JOB_ANNOTATIONS
      value:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for `podAnnotations` and `jobAnnotations` is not implemented yet in `spring-cloud/spring-cloud-scheduler-kubernetes` project. It'd be a port of exactly the same functionality that is already available in `spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes` project.

As discussed at [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues/428#issuecomment-488670392](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues/428#issuecomment-488670392), it can be implemented and released when it is ready.

Contributions welcome!